# What is the alt.topo_feature parameter for country India

Tags: python, visualization, altair

I am learning visualization using Altair python library. In the example section, I see codes for states of the USA.

```
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature='states')
```

I was wondering if the same can be applied to other countries like India, Brazil or China.

Where should I look to get the states for other countries? I want to plot visualization using Altair Python's library for visualization

```
import altair as alt
states = alt.topo_feature(data.us_10m.url, feature='states')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `data.us_10m` dataset contains borders of US states and counties at 10-meter-resolution. If you search the internet for "India topojson", you should be able to find a suitable dataset that covers India.

Comment: Hey @jakevdp i got some link India state data.The code is running fine,but it is not plotting anything.Am i doing anything wrong ? 
Also could you please provide any example for other countries which is not vega dataset.

import altair as alt
from vega_datasets import data

countries = alt.topo_feature('https://github.com/deldersveld/topojson/blob/master/countries/india/india-states.json',feature='states')

alt.Chart(countries).mark_geoshape(
    fill='lightgray',
    stroke='white'
).project(
    "equirectangular"
).properties(
    width=500,
    height=300
)

Comment: Code samples don't work well in comments. I can't help based on this. If you have another question, please post it as another question.

Comment: Sure @jakevdp ...Thanks anyway